# Improving a C++ class architecture where many classes derive from the same two bases

Tags: c++, architecture

I have a C++ architecture where I have many classes that all derive from two distinct base classes. All of the derived classes override/implement the same methods in the base classes in slightly different ways. To illustrate:

```
class B1 {
public:
    // method_1 is pure virtual.
    virtual void method_1() = 0;
};

class B2 {
public:
    // method_2 is not pure virtual.
    virtual void method_2();
};

class D1 : public B1, public B2 {
public:
    virtual void method_1() { // Does something... }
    virtual void method_2() { // Does something... }
};

class D2 : public B1, public B2 {
public:
    virtual void method_1() { // Does something slightly different... }
    virtual void method_2() { // Does something slightly different... }
};
```

Everything works fine, but being as there are about 20 derived classes, it feels like there *should* be a way to improve this design so that I have to write less code, especially as the derived classes are often quite similar in what they're doing. Can anyone offer me any pointers for the future?

Comment: Do they all inherit from `B1` and `B2`? Then you could start by replacing/merging `B1` and `B2` into a single class `B`.

Comment: Can method1 in general be implemented in terms of method2?

Comment: @Axel They all inherit from `B1` and `B2`, so I could do that. But my gut says this is bad since the two bases are distinct - I'll add a bit more to @Alexander L. Belikoff's answer. @Matteo, I don't think so.

Comment: why are there so many similar classes?

Comment: I think the first question would be whether the difference between `D1` and `D2` can be parameterized in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at strategy design pattern. Basically make methods 1 and 2 wrappers over B1 and B2 classes owned by unique pointers by class D. Then you can pass B1 and B2 instances in a constructor of D.

Comment: This looks like it might be an option. Could you please elaborate with an implementation, as although I can find a decent explanation of the pattern, the approach is a bit abstract for me (pardon the pun...)

Comment: I [implemented the pattern](http://ideone.com/V7aEoo), and although I can see the design benefit of implementing all the options via an interface, I've had to write more code here, not less. Hmmm.

Comment: Less code not necessarily mean better maintainability/flexibility/etc. In this particular case using two strategies instead of multiple inheritance can be useful when you have classes D with same function_1() but different function_2() for instance. Otherwise there is no immediate benefit, however it is considered nice to prefer composition over inheritance unless you have a good reason not to. Read this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-not-evil.html for a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

It is virtually impossible to analyze or suggest a *better* design without knowing the *domain* of your implementation (i.e. *what* exactly your program attempts to model). Making an extremely broad statement here, there are very few cases where using multiple inheritance in general form (i.e. beyond inheriting the behavior via the interfaces) is justified. Again, this is a blanket statement which still has some exceptions, depending on the domain.

Comment: Fair enough. The domain (I suppose) is a menuing system on an embedded processor. `B1` is an abstract callback class that all `D`s implement. `B2` is a Service class that emulates a tasking environment in the absence of an RTOS. All of the `D`s are "menu options" that the user can select to do something unique.

Comment: Hmm... Do you really need to inherit from `B2` then? Maybe using it instead of inheriting from it would be cleaner in this case? In that case, you only have a single "menu callback" class to inherit from.

Comment: I think I do (given my current design), since otherwise I can't see a neat way of having each menu option "serviced" by the underlying hardware timers? It feels like I would be introducing unnecessary gateways into the `D`s without deriving? How would I have affect the derived classes without introducing some other interface (and more code) if I didn't derive?